# Calling a method in viewDidLoad(). Work with indexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, sdk

I have TableView. My datasource is SQLite database. I'm trying to count a number of comments to some message (I know message id and it's text) for `numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfCommentsForMessage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Comments *comment = (Comments *)[appDelegate.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (MessageID == [comment.messageID integerValue]) {
        numberOfCommentsForMessage++;
     }
    NSLog(@"number of comments = %i",numberOfCommentsForMessage);
    return numberOfCommentsForMessage;
}
```

It isn't work even NSLog. I think this method should be called in `viewDidLoad()` but not sure that way is right.

**Editing**

Comments.h

```
@interface Comments : NSObject {
    NSString *messageID;
    NSString *commentText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *messageID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *commentText;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)mID commentText:(NSString *)cText;
```

MessageID I get from previous view:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
          MessageText:(NSString *)messageText
          MessageDate:(NSString *)messageDate
            MessageID:(NSInteger)messageID;
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        MessageText = [NSString stringWithString:messageText];
        MessageDate = [NSString stringWithString:messageDate];
        MessageID = messageID;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: We need more code than this. Please post where MessageID is defined, and your Comments.h header file.

Comment: But where are you calling `numberOfCommentsForMessage:` from now? Is it called at all?

Comment: If you're calling it more than once you're constantly increasing the counter, if you have 10 comments your numberOfCommentsForMessage will be 10 the first time, then 20, then 30 etc etc. This is why you should use a local variable in your method instead of a instance variable, see my post.

Comment: @VadimYelagin I'm calling it as another TableView methods, such as numberOfRowsInSection:, textForRowAtIndexPath: and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would also be interesting to know exactly what's not working. Does your application crash at NSLog or does it return the wrong message count?

Since you're returning `numberOfCommentsForMessage` from the method it would be desirable to reduce the scope of `numberOfCommentsForMessage` to a local variable within the method.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfCommentsForMessage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger numberOfComments = 0;
    MDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Comments *comment = (Comments *)[appDelegate.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (MessageID == [comment.messageID integerValue]) {
        numberOfComments++;
     }
    NSLog(@"number of comments = %d",numberOfComments);
    return numberOfComments;
}
```

Comment: Application is not crashing. I think this method does not calling at all. But why `numberOfCommentsForMessage` can't be local variable? Even if I synthesized it?

Comment: Since you're both returning the value and incrementing your instance variable, seems like a bug and/or anti pattern. 
If it's not crashing, what is happening that you find erroneous?

Comment: Any errors, any others bugs. Probably this method is not called at all. That's why I'm asking how to call it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding your English, but to call a class instance method in objective C with one parameter, the syntax would be: `[self someMethod:aParameter];`, add that to your `viewDidLoad` method.
You might want to check out a basic Objective C book for some general knowledge about the language.